# django configurable application settings

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have an application main page that should contain a lot of configurable parameters ( like banners, welcome text and so on ).
What is the best solution to store that data to avoid hardcode it in template and allow user to cnfigure it via admin panel?

Should I invent some config file and parse/modify it via admin interface?

The model "settings" with item-value doesn't look a good idea, as I need to store a different type of data ( text, integer, etc ). A way with a lot of models with just one-two rows looks excessive.

What is the best practice?

Comment: do you want to allow user to configure it via admin panel, but you don't want to save it in database? is that possible?

Comment: no. i just want to make it configurable, it doesn't matter if that is in database or in a file. but is it ok to have a lot of tables with just one or two rows to store a configs? or may be there is a bit smart way?

Comment: If the configs are peer user, yes

Comment: No, it is site-wide config.

Comment: Well, I don't thing that's possible. In Django admin you only can register Models, which are saved in database.

Comment: Yep, I understand that. Unfortunately to have an entire model for just a simple welcome text looks unreasonable. Nobody has such site-wide app settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all as I have about 20 setting items it was decided to create one model settings with field for each configurable item.

In that case I will have only one model and in the future it even can be expanded to use for similar use in neighbour apps.